# WordPress: How to query some specific static pages along with the latest post of a certain category?

Tags: wordpress

How to query some specific static pages along with the latest post of a certain category?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: can you please explain your question in details..?
it might be easy to get you..

Comment: I just want to get some specific static pages along with the latest post of a certain category into a variable `$query`.

Answer (score 2):

for that you have to make a template.

and give that to specific page.

and in that template give below code to call posts of a specific category.

Try this:

```
<?php

        $args2 = array(
            'numberposts' => 1,
            'cat' => 4,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_parent' => '',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'suppress_filters' => true
        );
        $homepage_content = get_posts($args2);

        foreach ($homepage_content as $key => $value) {
            echo "<h2>" . $value->post_title . "</h2>";
            echo $value->post_content;
            $post_id = $value->ID;
        }

?>
```

Here just pass ID of Category in cat argument.

```
For more reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts
```

-
Thanks

Comment: So I have to do another loop and cannot query everything, some specific static pages along with the latest post of a certain category, at once?